# "Invalid content type for feed" on my RSS feed (PHP / Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, rss, podcast

We create RSS feeds on our Wordpress-based website which have been working for 3-4 years. Suddenly, a couple of months ago, they have all become "invalid" in the eyes of Apple, Google, Spotify, and various RSS validators. The error I'm getting is "Invalid content type for feed" in this validator:

https://www.castfeedvalidator.com/validate.php?url=https://www.ananda.org/video/series/life-lessons-in-unexpected-places/podcast

The detailed view shows that, in the HTTP headers, the Content-Type is set to text/html, whereas I see nothing of the like when I navigate to it manually: https://www.ananda.org/video/series/life-lessons-in-unexpected-places/podcast

This is the beginning of my file (after setting some variables). Nothing strange that I can see. The headers are clearly sent as text/html :

```
/**
 * Output the podcast feed
 */
header("Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8");
//header("content-type: application/rss+xml; charset=utf-8");

echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?' . '>'; // Have to split up the PHP-triggering bit

?><rss version="2.0"
xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd"
```

Comment: Are you sure you submit the correct script to the validator?

Comment: The link I gave above is the same one I submitted to all the validators

Comment: I bet it is your webserver configuration. `curl -vvv -i https://www.ananda.org/video/series/life-lessons-in-unexpected-places/podcast` showed me https://pastebin.com/9MNQZZFV

Comment: I added this to my vhost `<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
</IfModule>

AddType application/rss+xml rss` using apache2. I don't know how to do with nginx.

Comment: Thanks! Server management is not my forte, though. I use Cloudways. Any chance you know how to work with that?

Comment: After looking again at the curl output I noticed, `<html><title>You are being redirected...</title>`... so that is the first answer! And then the HTML (<-- !!!) does the redirect, where a redirect should be 30x HTTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I got it. Markus Zeller proposed I check using `curl -vvv -i https://www.ananda.org/video/series/life-lessons-in-unexpected-places/podcast` . Once I did so, I saw that my Firewall (Sucuri) was blocking the requests. After adjusting the settings, things went back to normal.